# Cumulative Counts by Date Issue

Tags: mysql

I have a table that shows , for each date, a list of customer ids - shows customers who were active on any particular day. So each date can include ids that are also present in another date.

```
bdate            customer_id
2012-01-12       111
2012-01-13       222
2012-01-13       333
2012-01-14       111
2012-01-14       333
2012-01-14       666
2012-01-14       777
```

I am looking to write a query which calculates the total number of unique ids between two dates - the starting date is the row date and the ending date is a particular date in the future.

My query looks like this:

```
select
  bdate,
  count(distinct customer_id) as cts
from users
where bdate between bdate and current_date
group by 1
order by 1
```

But this produces a count of unique users for each date like this:

```
bdate            customer_id
2012-01-12       1
2012-01-13       2
2012-01-14       4
```

my desired result is ( for a count of users between starting row date and 2012-01-14 )

```
bdate            customer_id
2012-01-12       5  - includes (111,222,333,666,777)
2012-01-13       5  - includes (222,333,111,666,777)
2012-01-14       4  - includes (111,333,666,777)
```

Comment: See if you can make a join work for you

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

Like [**@Strawberry**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) said, you can make a join like this:

```
select
    t1.bdate,
    count(distinct t2.customer_id) as cts
from users t1
join users t2 on t2.bdate >= t1.bdate
where t1.bdate between t1.bdate and current_date
group by t1.bdate
order by t1.bdate
```

join t2 can get you all the users between particular day and `current_date`, then `count` t2's `customer_id`, that's it.

[**SqlFiddle Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3654c/4)

Comment: Hi - the query works but is timing out for me. The users table is rather huge.    Is there another way to run this more efficiently?

Comment: @user2022284, try to make particular day a explicit date, and I think if there is huge data, no matter what kind of solution it is, if you want more efficiently, you should do some optimization for your table, cause here is a `join` solution, if there is another, it may or should be a subquery solution, then you will also face the performance issue, because you have a huge data. ^^